# How to show div after Submit is complet instead click button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a contact form with many field forms. The form sends an e-mail, and I'd like to show a div (the div has css atributes display none, visible hidden) after the submit is complet.

When I use onClick, the div appear if I click a button with all empty forms.
Any help?

**My JavaScript function:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ipva_form_calculation').submit(function(event){
        $('.ipva_result').show();
            return false;
    });
});
```

**My HTML form:**

```
<form action="http://localhost/pedespachante/" method="post"       class="avia_ajax_form av-form-labels-hidden   avia-builder-el-4      el_after_av_heading  avia-builder-el-last  ipva_form_calculation av-centered-form  av-custom-form-color av-light-form" data-avia-form-id="1" data-avia-redirect="" style="display: none;">...</form>
```

Comment: so you want to display a div after a form is submitted ?

Comment: You need to use ajax and display the div once you get a successful result from the ajax call. Please post some of your code.

Comment: @mags I have posted some code.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `submit()` handler instead: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
  //do some form validations
  $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
          //one or more fields is empty, hence stop here
          return false;
      }
  });

  $('.div').show();
});
```

Comment: I did just that, but actualy not work :( I already add the code. @divix

Comment: You are still missing validations on inputs, I've added some sample validations to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use submit event of **JQuery**

```
$('#ur_form_id').submit(function(e) {
  $('.div_class_name').show();
});
```

Comment: Why do I have to use the e parameter? I did add the code, and does not work, check my updat.

Answer (score 0):

here is form

```
<form action="http://localhost/pedespachante/" method="post" id="form_id">
   <input type="text"  name="contact" />
   <div class="error" style="display:none;">Please Fill Contact</div>
</form>
```

here is jquery

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
   $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
    //one or more fields is empty, hence stop here
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('.error').show();
});
```

Hope its work for you!